# how to retain original value in ng-change

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to get a discounted value based on inputs and I want it to be dynamic, so I tried doing `ng-change="detail.total = detail.total - ((detail.discount/100)*detail.total)"` but it doesn't work because it would reference the newly changed `detail.total`, which in fact should be referencing the old, unchanged value.

here's a code snippet:

```
<ui-select ng-model="detail.item" theme="bootstrap" ng-change="detail.price = detail.item.price">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select item" allow-clear>{$$select.selected.name$}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="item in main.items | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, price: $select.search} | limitTo: 100">
            <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<input type="text" ng-model="detail.qty" ng-change="detail.total = (detail.qty * detail.price)">
<input type="text" ng-model="detail.price" ng-change="detail.total = (detail.qty * detail.price)">
<input type="text" ng-model="detail.discount" ng-change="detail.total = detail.total - ((detail.discount/100)*detail.total)>
<input readonly type="text" ng-model="detail.total">
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: tried to do it inside my controller -

```
this.new_total = function(total, discount){
    var total_c = angular.copy(total);
    var discount_c = angular.copy(discount);

    discount_c = discount_c/100;

    var final = total_c - (discount_c*total_c);
    return final;
}
```

then I called it by doing this:

```
<td><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="detail.discount" ng-change="detail.total = main.new_total(detail.total, detail.discount);"></td>
```

and it still has the same problem

Comment: use a different key for total. `ng-change="detail.totalAmount = ....` then bind that to your input element.

Comment: better way to call function on ng-change and do your logic part in controller (function) set variable . that variable value automatically pass to view because as we know angular is two way binding .

Comment: @YousafHassan I don't think this would work? See, I have a dropdown where I select an item, which has a price, and it would shown in a field once I'm done selecting. Then I input a quantity, which upon changing, would change `detail.total`.

Comment: @LeeMin your given code doesn't have any dropdown.

Comment: @Affan yep tried to do it that way and it still has the same problem. see my edit above

Comment: @YousafHassan edited the snippet in the question. my bad

Comment: Or you can add a watcher on this totalAmount. And copy this/use this oldValue wherever you want.

Comment: why not use **watchers**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use a function in your controller to update the total every time something changes.

See example below:

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("main", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.detail = {
        'item': null,
        'price': null,
        'qty': null,
        'discount': null,
        'total': null
    };
    
    $scope.updateTotal = function () {
      var totalBeforeDiscount = ($scope.detail.qty * $scope.detail.price);
      $scope.detail.total = totalBeforeDiscount - (totalBeforeDiscount * ($scope.detail.discount / 100));
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="main">
  <div>
    <label>Quantity</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="detail.qty" ng-change="updateTotal()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="detail.price" ng-change="updateTotal()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Discount (%)</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="detail.discount" ng-change="updateTotal()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Total</label>
    <input readonly type="text" ng-model="detail.total">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is somewhat similar to what I used. Thanks!